# Python type hinting: return type based on attribute

Tags: python, python-typing

Trying out type hinting, and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around something:

```py
class Node(object):
    credentials_class = credentials.BaseCredentials

    @property
    def credentials_instance(self) -> [credentials_class]:
        return self.credentials_class(self.credentials_data)


class OtherNode(Node):
    credentials_class = credentials.OtherCredentials  # subclass of BaseCredentials
```

How can I make it so that `OtherNode().credentials_instance` returns the type that is specified in `credentials_class`, for all subclasses of `Node`?

The `credentials_class` attribute is not required, if there is some other way for me to tell the system that "this node's credentials_instance property returns this instance type", that would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics). By making `Node` generic and parametrizing with the credentials class, you can specify the types as you want them to work. The downside is, the topmost class cannot assign a default value to `credentials_class`, because it'd conflict with it being generic.

```py
from typing import Type, Generic, TypeVar

CredentialsClassT = TypeVar("CredentialsClassT", bound=credentials.BaseCredentials)

class Node(Generic[CredentialsClassT]):
    credentials_class: Type[CredentialsClassT]

    @property
    def credentials_instance(self) -> CredentialsClassT:
        return self.credentials_class(self.credentials_data)

# example usage
class BaseNode(Node[credentials.BaseCredentials]):
    credentials_class = credentials.BaseCredentials

class OtherNode(Node[credentials.OtherCredentials]):
    credentials_class = credentials.OtherCredentials  # subclass of BaseCredentials
```

With that typing in place, eg.

```py
reveal_type(OtherNode.credentials_instance)
```

will make MyPy print `not: Revealed type is 'credentials.OtherCredentials'` as expected.